# MongoDB:latest docker container terminates with exit code 14

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-swarm, nfs, docker-swarm-mode

I'm making use of the mongodb:latest container for testing out WikiJS running in containers

On the odd occasion the mongodb container terminates with exit code 14, then Docker Swarm tries to restart it failing continuously with the same error - only work around so far has been to clear out the NFS share of all data before is successfully starts up

/data/db is mounted on an NFS share hosted on EMC Unity all flash storage with root access enabled

Anybody have any suggestions what to look at?  First time using MongoDB

Comment: Pull the docker log for that container. It should tell you why its dying.

Comment: @Adam if container is exited how can we get docker log ?

Comment: @VikrantPawar docker logs CONTAINER_NAME